# Write a new question or start a bounty?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, duplicates, bounty

I was drafting a question entitled, "How to make a group or department women-friendly?" when I noticed that the wonderful "Questions that may already have your answer" feature was pointing me helpfully to a related existing question: [What is being done to make the academic environment more women friendly?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/how-can-we-make-the-academic-enviroment-more-women-friendly).

Unfortunately, the existing how-can-we-make question received very little attention.  I would like to start a bounty on that question.  My only hesitation is that a user found fault with the question as written.

**What would be more effective -- set a bounty on the original question, or write a new question?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the real question is this: why aren't you satisfied with the answers to the original question?

- If you think that the original question would receive good answers if people paid more attention to it, then set a bounty.
- If you think that the original question didn't receive the answers you're looking for because it wasn't focused on the particular aspect of the problem you want, then ask a new question.  In the new question, link to the existing question and say why it doesn't answer your question already.

Answer (score 4):

I would only ask a new question, if it is new. If you ask a duplicate question, it will get closed. The original question is not great, but it is not awful either. I would try a bounty, if the question addresses the issue you are after.

I do not think my answer is great, but what type of answer are you looking for?